# Adding the values in multiple textboxes to a single textbox in php

Tags: javascript, php

I've a form which contains a div inside which contains a two textboxes one for service type and another for amount and an add more button. When i click on add more button. The div will get duplicated per onclick. Now I want the values in each amount textbox to be summed up and should be shown in another textbox total. I've created a JS function to show the value entered in amount textbox on **onkeyup**. But I didn't got any answer.

Here is the code what I've tried so far..

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr id="service">
        <td>
            <span>Service Type:</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="servicetype" id="servicetype" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Amount:</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" onkeyup="onkeyupsum()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="addmore" onclick="duplicate()" value="Add More"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4 style="text-align:left; padding:0,300px,300px,0;">Total Amount</h4></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tamt" id="tamt"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    function duplicate() 
    {                    // function to clone a div    
        var original = document.getElementById('service');
        var rows = original.parentNode.rows;
        var i = rows.length - 1;
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
        clone.id = "duplic" + (i); // there can only be one element with an ID
        original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, rows[i]);
    }
    function onkeyupsum()
    { // calculate sum and show in textbox
        var sum = 0;
        var amount1= document.getElementById('amount').value;
        sum += parseFloat(amount1);
        document.submitform.tamt.setAttribute("value",sum );
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me the way to take the textbox values even from duplicated div to textbox.

Comment: use Jquery for more flexibility for this kind of stuff. Answer with Jquery is allow  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to give inputs common class name and then in `onkeyupsum` select all inputs and calculate sum in loop:

```
function onkeyupsum() { // calculate sum and show in textbox
    var sum = 0,
        amount = document.querySelectorAll('.amount'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
        sum += parseFloat(amount[i].value || 0);
    }
    document.submitform.tamt.value = sum;
}
```

and input will look like:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" class="amount" onkeyup="onkeyupsum()" />
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mf7wqkq2/